# Json problem with Page Method call on IE 8

Tags: asp.net, javascript, internet-explorer, asp.net-ajax

I have the following code that populates a `select` element with values from an ajax call, via a *Page Method*.  In FF, the code works perfectly, in IE8 I get the error: ***'ResourceList[...].id' is null or not an object***.  What can I look at here?

```
    function readShift(jsonString) {
        var shiftInfo = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(jsonString);
        var listItems = "";

        listItems += "<option value='0'>[Unassigned]</option>";
        for (var i = 0; i < shiftInfo.ResourceList.length; i++) {
            listItems += "<option value='" + shiftInfo.ResourceList[i].id + "'>" + shiftInfo.ResourceList[i].name + "</option>";
        }
        $("#" + resourceListId).html(listItems);
     };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked this down to be an extra comma after my `ResourceList` array in the JSON.  FF handles it , IE not.  I was trimming my comma with

```
jsonReply.Remove(jsonReply.Length - 1, 1);
```

but that only trimmed the last `\n`, because I was using StringBuilder.AppendLine().  Changing the code to

```
jsonReply.Remove(jsonReply.Length - 3, 3);
```

solved the problem nicely.